# How to Make Character Shoot Where Aiming with Mouse

Tags: unity, 2d

I've looked around and none of the stuff I've found seem to help me. Here's my code so far. Right now it just shoots to the right (on purpose). Now how do I adjust my code to make the bullet go where I'm pointing with the mouse?

```
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class PlayerShooting : MonoBehaviour {

 public GameObject projectilePrefab;
 private List<GameObject> Projectiles = new List<GameObject>();
 private float projectileVelocity;

 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {
     projectileVelocity = 10;
 }

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {
     Shoot();
 }

 void Shoot()
 {
     if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
     {
         GameObject bullet = (GameObject)Instantiate(projectilePrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
         Projectiles.Add(bullet);
     }

     for (int i = 0; i < Projectiles.Count; i++)
     {
         GameObject goBullet = Projectiles[i];
         if (goBullet != null)
         {
             goBullet.transform.Translate(new Vector3(1, 0) * Time.deltaTime * projectileVelocity);

             Vector3 bulletScreenPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(goBullet.transform.position);
             if (bulletScreenPos.y >= Screen.height || bulletScreenPos.y <= 0)
             {
                 Destroy(goBullet);
                 Projectiles.Remove(goBullet);
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make projectiles shoot at mouse position?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/151892/how-to-make-projectiles-shoot-at-mouse-position)

Answer (score 0):

So there is multiple ways to go about this and none are correct or incorrect they just depend on how you want your game to function.

For example one method that makes sense for a bullet (It's not a heat seeking missile, it's fired from the gun and its momentum carries it in direction its facing) so I would create a script called Bullet for example :

**Method One**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Speed = 2.0f; //set your speed variable as a public float and 
    //you can adjust it from the inspector

    //Any Monobehaviour (Script you put on a GameObject) has this method 
    //and it's called every frame
    void Update()
    {
       //for very simple movement since this is a bullet and they move
       //towards the bullets forward direction 
       //(transform.forward * timesinceLastFrame * SpeeD)
        transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * Speed;
    }        

}
```

Now if you attach the script to your bullet prefab whenever you spawn the Bullet Prefab in PlayerShooting the script we attached will move it forward in the direction of its facing.

**Method Two**

But this wouldn't make sense for a heat seeking missile since they are given a target and track it's movement changing it's own direction so it stays on target.

You would need to calculate a Vector3 which has X, Y, Z co-ordinates for representing *something* in world space, everything that is in a scene in unity has a Transform Component which holds it's position.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Missile : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Speed = 2.0f;

    private GameObject target;

    void Update()
    {
        //if there is a target set
        if (this.target)
        { 
           //use our MoveTowards function to move to the targets position
            //which we get from its transform component
            MoveTowards(target.transform);
        }
    }

    public void SetTarget(GameObject _target)
    {
        this.target = _target;
    }

    void MoveTowards(Transform target)
    {  
        //to calculate a heading towards our target we can
        //subtract the current objects position (transform) 
        //from the targets position and that gives us a heading
        Vector3 vectorToTarget = target.position - transform.position;
        transform.position += vectorToTarget * Time.deltaTime * Speed;
    }
}
```

This is the same deal as before you add this script to your Missile Prefab but when we spawn it on left click in PlayerShooting we also want to set the Missiles target so it knows who to fly at we can do this using the SetTarget() public method and a RayCast.

I also tidied up your PlayerShooting a little.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerShooting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject projectilePrefab;
    //you can set the default value for variable when you declare it, if you 
    //set it public you can edit it in the inspector, which is handy for 
    //tweaking behaviour
    public float projectileVelocity = 10f;
    //added a float variable so you can set the max distance 
    //the target can be from the mouse
    public float maxRange = 50f;

    private List<GameObject> Projectiles = new List<GameObject>();

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Shoot();
    }

    void Shoot()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {

            //create a ray cast, which is quite honestly the same as how you would expect a laser pointer to work, you point it at something
            //in this case the mouse position translated to a world position
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;


            //if our ray cast hit anything 
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, maxRange))
            {

                Debug.Log("We hit " + hit.collider.gameObject.name);
                GameObject target = hit.collider.gameObject;
                //ok we have a target create the projectile,
                GameObject projectile = (GameObject)Instantiate(projectilePrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                //set its target
                projectile.GetComponent<Missile>().SetTarget(target);

                //add it to your list
                Projectiles.Add(projectile);
            }


        }
    }
}
```